# Image in HTTP Response using C?

Tags: html, c, web

I am writing a web server in **C**. I am able to send my html code in the response body but I tried an JPG image but I get **"http://localhost:port/image.jpg" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.**

this is a snippet from my webserver code:

> **this is my response header:**
>
> `char * responseheader= 
>     "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n 
>     "Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n"
>     "Content-Length: 110000\r\n\r\n";`
>
> **//read the file** *imagefile* **and store it in the buffer and append it to response header.**
>
> `for (i=0;(i<(sizeof(buffer))&&((ch=fgetc(imagefile))!=EOF)&&(ch!='\n')); i++) {
>          printf("%c", ch)
>          buffer[i] = ch; 
>    }`
>    `strcat(responseheader, buffer);`
>
> `if (strncmp(requestbuff, "GET /image.jpg", 15) 
>        {
>           printf("server: loading image...\n"); 
>           send(socketfd, responseheader, sizeof(responseheader), 0); 
>        }`

output:

on my webrowser *firefox*, I type localhost:port/index.html and the page loads fine. once my server reads the request **GET /image.jpg**..., I send the buffer above. Now, when my page loads, the image doesn't show up but as a small error box and when I right click on it and *view image,* it states the error above.

I'm not really sure how I can append the image with my response header. I tried sending the file directly to the web browser once I used *open()* after sending the response; same story. One thing I do know is that the image is "binary data", full of characters that I can see when I use notepad.

I've looked for hours, browsing the university library, and looking for books, but I haven't seen any implementation in HTTP/C to properly display an image.

Inside my **index.html** I used `<img src=/image.jpg></img>` which triggers the browser request to my web server.

Also, is there a book that any of you would recommend concerning HTTP and C web servers that covers this material? Thanks.

*Note: I understand this may be easier to implement in PHP/JAVA/JAVASCRIPT; I can only write this in C at the moment*

Best Regards.

Comment: 1) You have an additional `Content-type: text/html`, remove that. 2) Does the image really have exactly 110000 bytes? 3) Do not use `strcat()`, it stops at the first zero byte, use `memcpy()`. 4) You need a reasonable sized buffer for the `memcpy()`, which you have to allocate somehow (static or dyamic)

Comment: thanks for the response; that was a typo with the "content-type: text/html"; and the file image is 108642 according to ls-l

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues. firstly, you have a duplicate `Content-Type` header that is invalid (Forward-slash versus backslash, and also you're not sending HTML). Remove that first off.

Secondly, a binary file (such as a JPEG image) may (and often does) contain '00' bytes, which `strcat` will consider as string terminators.

Thirdly, you are invoking `strcat` to append to a pointer that may (as per the C standard) be stored in read-only memory (as it is a string literal).

Finally, `sizeof(responseheader)` is simply 4 or 8 (whatever the size of a pointer is on your system). You are conflating the behavior of `sizeof` on an array with its behavior on a pointer. You really mean `strlen(responseheader)` in the `send()` call.

In order to fix this all, I would use two `send()` calls (since HTTP uses TCP, they will be seen as a single stream of bytes). Do not modify `responseheader`, and simply send the header in the first call. Then, send the payload from the buffer in a second call, `send(socketfd, buffer, i, 0);` (after your `for` loop, `i`, will contain the number of bytes stored in `buffer`).

EDIT: also, you need to set `Content-Length` properly (to the size of your file of your file). Because of this change your response header creation to the following, with the `snprintf()` call AFTER your `for` loop to read the file:

```
char responseheader[80];

snprintf(responseheader, sizeof(responseheader),
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" 
    "Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n"
    "Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n", i
    );
```